# Getting correct frame after setting constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a method that creates a mask layer based on the current frame of my `UIImageView`, which works as I expected. However, in one case, I modify the height constraint of a `UIImageView` in the `viewWillAppear` method, and then apply the mask creator to the `UIImageView`, which creates a mask with a worng size. So my question is, how can I force to get the modified correct frame of that `UIImageView`?

Right now I'm getting the height 140 insted of 105, but if I use `layoutIfNeeded` after setting the constraint it become 118, which is closer, but still not 105.

**Updated:**

The method that I use for creating the mask:

```
public func setupMaskForImageView() {
    let mask = CALayer()
    let resizedMaskImage = resizeImage(UIImage(named: imageMaskName)!, newSize: frame.size)
    mask.contents = resizedMaskImage
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)
    layer.mask = mask
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

and I modified the constraint in `viewWillAppear` with

```
imageHeight.constant = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2.5
```

Comment: I try to keep the majority of my framing in layoutSubviews.  Have you tried setting the frame there so it's updated whenever views are need reframing?

Comment: @joels The view which I try to set its frame is not a sublcass of UIView, so setting in layoutSubviews is not available unfortunately.

Comment: How do you add the mask and how do you update its constraint.

Comment: What is the relationship between `layer` and the `imageView`. Did you mean that the `layer` frame is not equal to the `imageView`'s?

Comment: @sahara108 yes, exaclty.

Comment: Ok, I can't help because I don't know how you set up your `imageView` and `layer`. The only thing I can tell is that you need a way to know when your `imageView` frame changed and notify to update `layer`'s frame. I suggest you update `layer`'s frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of your view controller

Comment: @joels in the end, I used what you suggested, subclassed UIImageView and set the constraints in layoutSubviews. If you think, create an answer with that and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always ideal to keep your framing kept in `layoutSubviews`.  From the Apple developer UIKit [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html):

> `layoutSubviews` - Implement this method if you need more precise control over the layout of your subviews than either the constraint or autoresizing behaviors provide.

That being said, your best option is probably to create a subclass for your custom UIImageView and insert your reframing logic in `layoutSubviews`.  This will ensure your view and mask are always properly framed.